# Indexing numpy record arrays is very slow

Tags: performance, numpy

It looks like indexing numpy record arrays with an array of indices is outrageously slow. However, the same operation can be performed using `np.view` 10-15 times faster.

Is there a reason behind this difference? Why isn't indexing of record arrays implemented in a faster way? (see also [sorting numpy structured and record arrays is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682521/sorting-numpy-structured-and-record-arrays-is-very-slow))

```
mydtype = np.dtype("i4,i8")
mydtype.names = ("foo","bar")
N = 100000

foobar = np.zeros(N,dtype = mydtype)
foobar["foo"] = np.random.randint(0,100,N)
foobar["bar"] = np.random.randint(0,10000,N)

b = np.lexsort((foobar["foo"],foobar["bar"]))

timeit foobar[b]
100 loops, best of 3: 11.2 ms per loop

timeit foobar.view("|S12")[b].view(mydtype)
1000 loops, best of 3: 882 µs per loop
```

Obviously, both results give the same answer.

Comment: Maybe it is for the reason that lexsort sorts the array while view just creates a view!? I think this question could also be asked in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ !

Comment: Raising this issue on the numpy github might be more productive.  Those are the people who know their way around the numpy source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`take`, as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/23303357/901925, is even faster than your double view approach:

```
np.take(foobar,b)
```

In fact it's as fast as

```
foobar['foo'][b]
```

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/item_selection.c is a starting point if you want to dig further in to the source code.

My guess is that something in how `__getitem__` is implemented causes this difference.  Maybe as a remnant of earlier record processing it takes a different path when the `dtype` is mixed (and for advanced indexing).

Boolean mask indexing doesn't seem to be affected by this slow down.  Same for basic sliced indexing.