# Memory efficient sort of massive numpy array in Python

Tags: python, performance, sorting, numpy, memory

I need to sort a VERY large genomic dataset using numpy. I have an array of 2.6 billion floats, dimensions = `(868940742, 3)` which takes up about 20GB of memory on my machine once loaded and just sitting there. I have an early 2015 13' MacBook Pro with 16GB of RAM, 500GB solid state HD and an 3.1 GHz intel i7 processor. Just loading the array overflows to virtual memory but not to the point where my machine suffers or I have to stop everything else I am doing.

I build this VERY large array step by step from 22 smaller `(N, 2)` subarrays.

Function `FUN_1` generates 2 new `(N, 1)` arrays using each of the 22 subarrays which I call `sub_arr`.

The first output of `FUN_1` is generated by interpolating values from `sub_arr[:,0]` on array `b = array([X, F(X)])` and the second output is generated by placing `sub_arr[:, 0]` into bins using array `r = array([X, BIN(X)])`. I call these outputs `b_arr` and `rate_arr`, respectively. The function returns a 3-tuple of `(N, 1)` arrays:

```
import numpy as np

def FUN_1(sub_arr):
    """interpolate b values and rates based on position in sub_arr"""

    b = np.load(bfile)
    r = np.load(rfile)

    b_arr = np.interp(sub_arr[:,0], b[:,0], b[:,1])
    rate_arr = np.searchsorted(r[:,0], sub_arr[:,0])  # HUGE efficiency gain over np.digitize...

    return r[rate_r, 1], b_arr, sub_arr[:,1]
```

I call the function 22 times in a for-loop and fill a pre-allocated array of zeros `full_arr = numpy.zeros([868940742, 3])` with the values:

```
full_arr[:,0], full_arr[:,1], full_arr[:,2] = FUN_1
```

In terms of saving memory at this step, I think this is the best I can do, but I'm open to suggestions. Either way, I don't run into problems up through this point and it only takes about 2 minutes.

Here is the sorting routine (there are two consecutive sorts)

```
for idx in range(2):
    sort_idx = numpy.argsort(full_arr[:,idx])
    full_arr = full_arr[sort_idx]
    # ...
    # <additional processing, return small (1000, 3) array of stats>
```

Now this sort had been working, albeit slowly (takes about 10 minutes). However, I recently started using a larger, more fine resolution table of `[X, F(X)]` values for the interpolation step above in `FUN_1` that returns `b_arr` and now the SORT really slows down, although everything else remains the same.

Interestingly, I am not even sorting on the interpolated values at the step where the sort is now lagging. Here are some snippets of the different interpolation files - the smaller one is about 30% smaller in each case and far more uniform in terms of values in the second column; the slower one has a higher resolution and many more unique values, so the results of interpolation are likely more unique, but I'm not sure if this should have any kind of effect...?

**bigger, slower file:**

```
17399307    99.4
17493652    98.8
17570460    98.2
17575180    97.6
17577127    97
17578255    96.4
17580576    95.8
17583028    95.2
17583699    94.6
17584172    94
```

**smaller, more uniform regular file:**

```
1       24  
1001    24  
2001    24  
3001    24  
4001    24  
5001    24
6001    24
7001    24
```

I'm not sure what could be causing this issue and I would be interested in any suggestions or just general input about sorting in this type of memory limiting case!

Comment: Why don't you sort the large array as you construct it - e.g. during the interpolation or the merging of the small arrays? You can use In-place Merge Sort as it uses O(1) memory.

Comment: Didn't understand your whole question, but if you need to sort a dataset that is larger than memory, you might have a look at [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort). They usued that back in the days to [sort large data sets on tapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Use_with_tape_drives), when main memory was only some kilobytes.

Comment: @StoyanDekov hey, thanks for your input. I'm not sure I understand how that would work but maybe you can clue me in. Say I sort `sub_arr1` along column 1 and then `sub_arr2` comes up and it's column 1 values bisect the sorted `sub_arr1` all over the place, are you saying that with merged sort I can just insert these columns into the growing array at the correct indices and then move to the next `sub_arrN` ?

Comment: @BasSwinckels thanks to you as well Bas, I am going to look into that. Before I discovered how efficient NumPy could be with large data I had actually trying to think up some way to sort my data sequentially by putting breaking it up similarly to the way your linked article describes, although I didn't quite manage to wrap my head around it ;-). The issue that is bugging me here is that the size hasn't changed, just the composition of one of the data columns, and that somehow put the breaks on my program, so I was trying to figure out why that might be... Cheers!

Comment: @YXD hey, not sure what you mean exactly by that... do you mean build a database for my dataset and create "keys" or some kind of indexing system to return the sorted data? I think I wrote the question badly, TBH my main issue is trying to figure out why the same size array is more difficult to sort depending on its contents, although intuitively it makes sense as there are probably more comparisons to make... but I don't really understand how these things are represented internally or anything, I am still quite a noob ;-)

Comment: @ali_m hey thanks for the edits, I will be more careful on future posts :-)

Comment: @isosceleswheel I didn't catch all the details, my fault for not reading carefully. Yes I was suggesting building a database and setting an index on the relevant columns.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At the moment each call to `np.argsort` is generating a `(868940742, 1)` array of int64 indices, which will take up ~7 GB just by itself. Additionally, when you use these indices to sort the columns of `full_arr` you are generating another `(868940742, 1)` array of floats, since [fancy indexing always returns a copy rather than a view](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays).

One fairly obvious improvement would be to sort `full_arr` in place using its [`.sort()` method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html). Unfortunately, `.sort()` does not allow you to directly specify a row or column to sort by. However, you *can* specify a field to sort by for a structured array. You can therefore force an inplace sort over one of the three columns by getting a [`view`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) onto your array as a structured array with three float fields, then sorting by one of these fields:

```
full_arr.view('f8, f8, f8').sort(order=['f0'], axis=0)
```

In this case I'm sorting `full_arr` in place by the 0th field, which corresponds to the first column. Note that I've assumed that there are three float64 columns (`'f8'`) - you should change this accordingly if your dtype is different. This also requires that your array is contiguous and in row-major format, i.e. `full_arr.flags.C_CONTIGUOUS == True`.

Credit for this method should go to Joe Kington for his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2828371/1461210).

---

Although it requires less memory, sorting a structured array by field is unfortunately much slower compared with using `np.argsort` to generate an index array, as you mentioned in the comments below (see [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19682521/1461210)). If you use `np.argsort` to obtain a set of indices to sort by, you might see a modest performance gain by using `np.take` rather than direct indexing to get the sorted array:

```
 %%timeit -n 1 -r 100 x = np.random.randn(10000, 2); idx = x[:, 0].argsort()
x[idx]
# 1 loops, best of 100: 148 µs per loop

 %%timeit -n 1 -r 100 x = np.random.randn(10000, 2); idx = x[:, 0].argsort()
np.take(x, idx, axis=0)
# 1 loops, best of 100: 42.9 µs per loop
```

However I wouldn't expect to see any difference in terms of memory usage, since both methods will generate a copy.

---

Regarding your question about why sorting the second array is faster - yes, you should expect any reasonable sorting algorithm to be faster when there are fewer unique values in the array because on average there's less work for it to do. Suppose I have a random sequence of digits between 1 and 10:

```
5  1  4  8  10  2  6  9  7  3
```

There are 10! = 3628800 possible ways to arrange these digits, but only one in which they are in ascending order. Now suppose there are just 5 unique digits:

```
4  4  3  2  3  1  2  5  1  5
```

Now there are 2⁵ = 32 ways to arrange these digits in ascending order, since I could swap any pair of identical digits in the sorted vector without breaking the ordering.

By default, `np.ndarray.sort()` uses [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). The [`qsort`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Repeated_elements) variant of this algorithm works by recursively selecting a 'pivot' element in the array, then reordering the array such that all the elements less than the pivot value are placed before it, and all of the elements greater than the pivot value are placed after it. Values that are equal to the pivot are already sorted. Having fewer unique values means that, on average, more values will be equal to the pivot value on any given sweep, and therefore fewer sweeps are needed to fully sort the array.

For example:

```
%%timeit -n 1 -r 100 x = np.random.random_integers(0, 10, 100000)
x.sort()
# 1 loops, best of 100: 2.3 ms per loop

%%timeit -n 1 -r 100 x = np.random.random_integers(0, 1000, 100000)
x.sort()
# 1 loops, best of 100: 4.62 ms per loop
```

In this example the dtypes of the two arrays are the same. If your smaller array has a smaller item size compared with the larger array then the cost of copying it due to the fancy indexing will also be smaller.

Comment: I think I should have elaborated more on the last paragraph of my question, the details were meant to help identify the issue, but I'm not looking for the best solution per se; rather an understanding of the nature of the problem. I'm interested as to why sorting two identically sized and formatted arrays would lead to such different memory demands. The only difference is that the "slower" array has a larger set of unique values. Ultimately, it seems that `sort([2,1,1,4,3])` takes more resources than `sort([1.66453, 2.899, 4.9034, 1.43235, 2.3464])` and I'm curious as to why... :-)

Comment: by the way (ran out of space!), thanks for the suggestion, ultimately via Joe, to try `full_arr.view('f8, f8, f8').sort(order=['f0'], axis=0)`, I hadn't seen this use of `view` before.

Comment: unfortunately, the structured array approach is significantly slower than the other more memory heavy ones, and even with just the first 10% of `full_arr` I timeout. I think I recall seeing somewhere else on this site that structured arrays have the downside of being quite a bit slower for various jobs.

Answer (score 8):

### EDIT: In case anyone new to programming and `numpy` comes across this post, I want to point out the importance of considering the `np.dtype` that you are using. In my case, I was actually able to get away with using half-precision floating point, i.e. `np.float16`, which reduced a 20GB object in memory to 5GB and made sorting much more manageable. The default used by `numpy` is `np.float64`, which is a lot of precision that you may not need. Check out the [doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html) here, which describes the capacity of the different data types. Thanks to @ali_m for pointing this out in the comments.

I did a bad job explaining this question but I have discovered some helpful workarounds that I think would be useful to share for anyone who needs to sort a truly massive `numpy` array.

I am building a very large `numpy` array from 22 "sub-arrays" of human genome data containing the elements `[position, value]`. Ultimately, the final array must be numerically sorted "in place" based on the values in a particular column and without shuffling the values within rows.

The sub-array dimensions follow the form:

```
arr1.shape = (N1, 2)
...
arr22.shape = (N22, 2)
```

`sum([N1..N2]) = 868940742` i.e. there are close to 1BN positions to sort.

First I process the 22 sub-arrays with the function `process_sub_arrs`, which returns a 3-tuple of 1D arrays the same length as the input. I stack the 1D arrays into a new `(N, 3)` array and insert them into an `np.zeros` array initialized for the full dataset:

```
    full_arr = np.zeros([868940742, 3])
    i, j = 0, 0

    for arr in list(arr1..arr22):  
        # indices (i, j) incremented at each loop based on sub-array size
        j += len(arr)
        full_arr[i:j, :] = np.column_stack( process_sub_arrs(arr) )
        i = j

    return full_arr
```

### EDIT: Since I realized my dataset could be represented with half-precision floats, I now initialize `full_arr` as follows: `full_arr = np.zeros([868940742, 3], dtype=np.float16)`, which is only 1/4 the size and much easier to sort.

Result is a massive 20GB array:

```
full_arr.nbytes = 20854577808
```

As @ali_m pointed out in his detailed post, my earlier routine was inefficient:

```
sort_idx = np.argsort(full_arr[:,idx])
full_arr = full_arr[sort_idx]
```

the array `sort_idx`, which is 33% the size of `full_arr`, hangs around and wastes memory after sorting `full_arr`. This sort supposedly generates a copy of `full_arr` due to "fancy" indexing, potentially pushing memory use to 233% of what is already used to hold the massive array! This is the slow step, lasting about ten minutes and relying heavily on virtual memory.

I'm not sure the "fancy" sort makes a persistent copy however. Watching the memory usage on my machine, it seems that `full_arr = full_arr[sort_idx]` deletes the reference to the unsorted original, because after about 1 second all that is left is the memory used by the sorted array and the index, even if there is a transient copy.

A more compact usage of `argsort()` to save memory is this one:

```
    full_arr = full_arr[full_arr[:,idx].argsort()]
```

This still causes a spike at the time of the assignment, where both a transient index array and a transient copy are made, but the memory is almost instantly freed again.

@ali_m pointed out a nice trick (credited to Joe Kington) for generating a de facto *structured array* with a `view` on `full_arr`. The benefit is that these may be sorted "in place", maintaining stable row order:

```
full_arr.view('f8, f8, f8').sort(order=['f0'], axis=0)
```

Views work great for performing mathematical array operations, but for sorting it is far too inefficient for even a single sub-array from my dataset. In general, structured arrays just don't seem to scale very well even though they have really useful properties. If anyone has any idea why this is I would be interested to know.

One good option to minimize memory consumption and improve performance with very large arrays is to build a pipeline of small, simple functions. Functions clear local variables once they have completed so if intermediate data structures are building up and sapping memory this can be a good solution.

This a sketch of the pipeline I've used to speed up the massive array sort:

```
def process_sub_arrs(arr):
    """process a sub-array and return a 3-tuple of 1D values arrays"""

    return values1, values2, values3

def build_arr():
    """build the initial array by joining processed sub-arrays"""

    full_arr = np.zeros([868940742, 3])
    i, j = 0, 0

    for arr in list(arr1..arr22):  
        # indices (i, j) incremented at each loop based on sub-array size
        j += len(arr)
        full_arr[i:j, :] = np.column_stack( process_sub_arrs(arr) )
        i = j

    return full_arr

def sort_arr():
    """return full_arr and sort_idx"""

    full_arr = build_arr()
    sort_idx = np.argsort(full_arr[:, index])

    return full_arr[sort_idx]

def get_sorted_arr():
    """call through nested functions to return the sorted array"""

    sorted_arr = sort_arr()
    <process sorted_arr>

    return statistics
```

call stack: get_sorted_arr --> sort_arr --> build_arr --> process_sub_arrs

Once each inner function is completed `get_sorted_arr()` finally just holds the sorted array and then returns a small array of statistics.

### EDIT: It is also worth pointing out here that even if you are able to use a more compact `dtype` to represent your huge array, you will want to use higher precision for summary calculations. For example, since `full_arr.dtype = np.float16`, the command `np.mean(full_arr[:,idx])` tries to calculate the mean in half-precision floating point, but this quickly overflows when summing over a massive array. Using `np.mean(full_arr[:,idx], dtype=np.float64)` will prevent the overflow.

I posted this question initially because I was puzzled by the fact that a dataset of identical size suddenly began choking up my system memory, although there was a big difference in the proportion of unique values in the new "slow" set. @ali_m pointed out that, indeed, more uniform data with fewer unique values is easier to sort:

> The qsort variant of Quicksort works by recursively selecting a
>   'pivot' element in the array, then reordering the array such that all
>   the elements less than the pivot value are placed before it, and all
>   of the elements greater than the pivot value are placed after it.
>   Values that are equal to the pivot are already sorted, so intuitively,
>   the fewer unique values there are in the array, the smaller the number
>   of swaps there are that need to be made.

On that note, the final change I ended up making to attempt to resolve this issue was to round the newer dataset in advance, since there was an unnecessarily high level of decimal precision leftover from an interpolation step. This ultimately had an even bigger effect than the other memory saving steps, showing that the sort algorithm itself was the limiting factor in this case.

Look forward to other comments or suggestions anyone might have on this topic, and I almost certainly misspoke about some technical issues so I would be glad to hear back :-)

Comment: If you're happy to round your data then I would also consider switching to a dtype with a smaller item size in order to reduce your memory requirements. If you still need to store fractional values then you could just switch to a less precise float, e.g. np.float64 --> np.float32. If you only need integer values then you could switch to a smaller integer type, e.g. np.int32/np.uint32 or even np.int16/np.uint16 depending on the largest value you need to represent. You should also probably try using `np.take` instead of array indexing to get your sorted array, if you haven't already.

Comment: Hi @ali_m, thanks again for all the useful feedback. Do you know where I could find a clear discussion of the limitations of dtypes for floats and ints? I am googling and finding discussions for specific applications of float64 vs. float32 but I am just trying to understand the range that these types are able to represent e.g. is float64 just a decimal out to 16 places vs 8 places for float32, and I suppose, 4 places for 16? What is the limitation imposed by int32 vs. int64? The 3 columns of `full_arr` are actually pretty low precision, at most out to 6 decimals for one of them.

Comment: @ali_m actually it was right there in the docs: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html