# Reducing memory usage when indexing in Numpy

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, memory, indexing

I have a large Numpy matrix `act` with `dtype=np.float32` and two vectors of the same length, `raw_id` and `raw_label`. I want to sort all 3 objects based on the values in `raw_id`. However, I get a memory error when running this script. I've isolated it to `act[sortind,:]` in the function below. How can I optimize the memory usage?

The arrray `act` is roughly `1400000 x 400`, whereas `raw_id` and `raw_label` is `1400000 x 1` using `dtype=np.float64`. It will almost fit into my 12gb of memory along with the remaining variables that I have initialised.

```
def sort_by_id(act, raw_id, raw_label):
    sortind = np.argsort(raw_id)
    return act[sortind,:], raw_id[sortind], raw_label[sortind]

# calling function with same variables
act, raw_id, raw_label = sort_by_id(act, raw_id, raw_label)
```

Comment: This is probably because [fancy indexing always returns a copy rather than a view](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26239802/1461210

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31359980/1461210

Comment: How big is your array? How much RAM do you have?

Comment: Thanks for the related posts - I'm looking into them. See my update regarding the size and RAM.

Comment: A 1400000 * 400 array of 32bit floats is only ~2.24 GB. What are `raw_id` and `raw_label` like?

Comment: See my update. That sounds strange.. I'll investigate further.